# Foreach Loop using MySQL Query?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I ran into this problem earlier but I didn't ask it because I found a work around, however Im not so lucky this time.

I am trying to create a simple list for each "pg.pcat" (page category) to show 5 latest links from each category (I am aware I didn't add `LIMIT` or `ORDER BY`).

```
$q2 = "
SELECT pg.pcat, p.page_id, p.link_title 
FROM pages AS P 
INNER JOIN page_categories AS pg ON pg.pc_id = $sidenav
";

$r2 = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q2); // Run the Query.  

while ($qarr = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if(!isset($printed)) { 
        echo "<div class=\"sideNavSpan\">{$qarr['pcat']}</div>";
        $printed = true;
    }
    echo "
    <li>
     <a href=\"page.php?pid={$qarr['page_id']}\">{$qarr['link_title']}</a>
    </li>
    ";
}
```

I need something like this but I can't figure out how to use a for loop on the values in `$qarr`.

```
----pg.pcat1
p.link_title
p.link_title
p.link_title
p.link_title
p.link_title

----pg.pcat2
p.link_title
p.link_title
p.link_title
p.link_title
p.link_title

----pg.pcat3
p.link_title
p.link_title
p.link_title
p.link_title
p.link_title
```

etc.
help? please and thank you :)

Comment: FYI - You're missing the closing `</li>` tag. Also aren't you going to wrap your list items in a list like `<ul>'?

Comment: @Naveed - In HTML AFAIK you do not need the closing tag for LI's. In XHTML you do, but not in HTML. Although it is a good practice to do so (I added it in my edit before you mentioned it, btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to order by pg.pcat in your SQL query, and wrap the whole of this in an if test to ensure that at least one row has been returned

```
$currCat = '';
$printed = false;
while ($qarr = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {     
   if($currCat != $qarr['pcat']) {  // category has changed
      if ($printed) { // we already printed an opening <ul> so we need to close it
         echo '</ul>';
         $printed = true;
      }
      echo"<div class=\"sideNavSpan\">{$qarr['pcat']}</div><ul>";
      $currCat = $qarr['pcat'];
   }
   echo "<li><a href=\"page.php?pid={$qarr['page_id']}\">{$qarr['link_title']}</a></li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: @Mark Baker - What about a `GROUP BY`? Would that also help?

Comment: I see where you're going with this, i tried to do something similar incrementing $sidenav which was my equivalent to your currcat. I thought a foreach loop would be the way to go, but i think ill stick with this method.

Comment: @luckycypher - Make sure and click the outlined checkmark under this answer's vote tally if it's the answer you use. :)

Comment: @Jared - Nope, GROUP BY is used when you want to aggregate values from several rows into a single returned row

Comment: @Mark Baker - Thanks. Can you tell I've not really used it a whole lot?

Comment: @Jared - everything is new to everybody at some point in their lives

Comment: @Mark - I was overthinking the problem by, ironically, trying to keep it simple. I've been taught that you make the query do as much of the hard work as possible, when possible, it just so happens in this case it didn't to do any more work.

Comment: @Jared - a solution using GROUP BY would be to use the group_concat() function for the page id and link title, then loop through the returned categories, display each one, then explode the returned page ids and titles to build the list for each.

Comment: @Jared - slightly more work in this case, with 2 fields that would need exploding and then merging the two arrays, but if it was just to display a list of titles without the actual anchor links, then it could be done in less PHP code